# For textarea leap up in jquery mobile

Tags: html

I am using fixed position in footer but when I click in textarea then whole dive leap up. Please see below code and share with me solution as soon as possible.

```
    <div class="add-post" id="addCommentPart" data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
        <textarea placeholder="Add Comment..." id="comments" data-prevent-focus-zoom="false"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post" title="Post" class="post-btn"  onClick="sendMessage();">
    </div>
```

Comment: please add your code..?

Comment: plz add your code on jsfiddle...

Comment: http://183.182.84.84/rise/issueview.html

I can't share code because it's phonegap application and the content coming by dynamic. I have make all HTML in jquery mobile. I have put images from app. it's Iphone 4s view In first image textarea is not performing any action. In second screen when we click on textarea, textarea goes up as I shared in issue.